Java's split method work differently on different strings
I'm trying spliting strings by using String.split() method.
And when I use
String test = "a          ";
String[] split = test .split(" ");

this array's length is 1.
But when I use
String test2 = "\"a          \"";
String[] split = test2 .split(" ");

this array's length is 11 and it contains many "" string.
And I'm confused about this result...
I can't understand why the split(" ") work differently on different strings.
And I hope somebody can tell me why...

if some method is not doing as you expect, at least then check its documentation: "This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array." (emphasis added), also check the two-argument method's documentation, same page

( use ...split(" ", -1) to keep the trailing empty strings )
